# Is default template template parameter value deduced context?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I was actually surprised that both gcc and clang accept this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, template <class, class = T> class TT, class Y>
T foo(TT<Y>) {
}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo(std::vector<int>{})), std::allocator<int>>::value);
}
```

Are gcc and clang right that the values of the default template template parameters are deduced context or is it compilers extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
template <class T, template <class, class = T> class TT, class Y>
T foo(TT<Y>);
```

it is equivalent to

```
template <class T, template <class, class = T> class TT, class Y>
T foo(TT<Y, T>);
```

So `T` can be deduced.

Comment: That makes sense, however it still looks like a compilers trick, is it guaranteed by standard?

Comment: @W.F. Maybe it's implied from § 14.3.3/3? (N4296)

Comment: @AndyG it looks like it could explain it, let me analyse it a bit more...

Comment: @AndyG I'm not sure. My understanding of the fragment is that it the the template template parameter matches if the classes of the template parameters match... I think it is referring to the type/template template/non-type template parameters and no default values of any kind of parameters... but I might misunderstood that fragment as I'm not a native... :(